# check IPs with multiple ports from csv

Tags: shell-script, ip, csv

is there possibility to simply check IP address with ports from csv file?

My csv has hundred of IPs in this format

```
123.123.321.321:80,22,443
223.223.321.321:80,22,443
```

Is there possibility to check IPs in this order and format via bash script to make it automatic?

Comment: Do you want to check if the IPs are valid? Or if the server on these IPs and these ports is reachable? Your example uses invalid IPs (the components of IP addresses must be numbers between 1 and 255), is that what you intended?

Comment: I want to check if server is reachable on ports which are on the same line as the IP address.

Ye I know, it's just a example IP, I don't want to expose my servers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while IFS=: read -r ip ports; do
   savIFS=$IFS
   IFS=,; set -f; set -- $ports; r=
      while case $# in 0 ) break ;; esac; do
         nc "$ip" "$1" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
         r=${r:-$ip:}${r:+,($?)}$1
         shift
      done
      echo "$r"
   IFS=$savIFS
done < yourcsvfile
```

Now all the ports which are enclosed in nonzero are closed while (0) are open.

Per OP request a per-IP, status message is generated:

```
while IFS=: read -r ip ports; do
   savIFS=$IFS
   IFS=,; set -f; set -- $ports
      for port
      do
         nc "$ip" "$port" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
         case $? in
            0 ) status="PASS" ;;
            * ) status="FAIL" ;;
         esac
         echo "$ip:$port - $status"
      done
   IFS=$savIFS
done < yourcsvfile
```

Comment: how can I add some "status" when is connection test finished? I mean "OK or FAIL" or something?

Comment: Well per IP adress, I would be very grateful for this format on output

IP:PORT - FAIL, and if it will get output to file is that possible? Your Bash script is too advance for me to edit..

Comment: it proceed and thats all, no output

Comment: It looks nice, but somehow there is missing first 5 digits of tested IP. Its overwriten by "FAIL" oO

Comment: yes..probably. Don't know why, but FAIL is printed first .. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Use printf in place of echo: `printf '%s:%s-%s\n' "$ip" "$port" "$status"` and also remove your comments from this discussion thread.